# C# calling method via reflection with parameters passed inline and as local variables

Tags: c#, reflection

I have following code. It has problem. The call to
MyMethod does not return the correct result set based on the
input value passed.

```
foreach (var input in inputCollection)
            {

var result = myInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethod",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
    null,
    myInstance,
    new Object[] { input })
}
```

Instead, if I do as following, it works as expected and returns
different output based on the supplied input value.

```
foreach (var input in inputCollection)
            {
var args = new Object[] { input };

var result = myInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethod",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
    null,
    myInstance,
    args)
}
```

What could possibly be the difference here if I pass argument inline with object initializer and via local 
variable?

Edit:
In the not working code, it always returns result for the first item of InputCollection regardless current iterating value of input.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: No difference. Your problem is somewhere else. Please post the actual code (as the code you have posted does not even compile...). See [Create an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is `inputCollection` a collection or `IEnumerable` produced through LINQ with deferred execution? Are you printing/consuming `result` right away, or is there something else going on that has to do with deferred execution?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes. I consume result right away. And it is inputCollection is List<T> where T is any class.

Comment: @JayNanavaty Then there's something else going on. Try reproducing it in an isolated example - say, on ideone.com, and post a link to a live sample that is broken.

Comment: Apart from that you need `BindingFlags.Instance` unless the method is static (in which case you wouldn't pass `myInstance` to `InvokeMember`), these should be identical. I've taken the time to [prove it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QktTps). So something else is going on

Comment: Thanks @Jcl I am also preparing some sample code to share and see if I can reproduce the same problem in simple code. My actual code is bit complex with generics and I think it is better if I put simplified version of it.